# using find in pandas dataframe in str range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column

```
   code
0. Slip - Trans:S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683Store:S-BRT4Terminal:S-BRT4
1. Slip - Trans:M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459Store:M-BXP2Terminal:M-BXP2
2. Slip - Trans:M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949Store:M-YyL2Terminal:M-YyL2
```

I want to specific string (below bold) in another column named 'TTT' like following

```
   code                                                          TTT
0. Slip - Trans:**S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683**Store:S-BRT4Terminal:S-BRT4   S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683
1. Slip - Trans:**M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459**Store:M-BXP2Terminal:M-BXP2    M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459
2. Slip - Trans:**M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949**Store:M-YyL2Terminal:M-YyL2   M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949
```

The start Number is fixed 13 and the end is dynamic so i am using Find('Store:') in the `.str`, I am using following code

```
df['TTT']= df['code'].str[13:df['code'].str.find('Store:')]
```

the above code is giving me `NaN` instead of required string.

that is not working can you help me about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need values between `Trans:`: and `Store:` use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['TTT']= df['code'].str.extract('Trans:(.*)Store:', expand=False)
print (df)
                                                code                  TTT
0  Slip - Trans:S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683Store:S-BRT4Te...  S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683
1  Slip - Trans:M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459Store:M-BXP2Ter...   M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459
2  Slip - Trans:M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949Store:M-YyL2Te...  M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949
```

Another idea with double `split`:

```
df['TTT']= df['code'].str.split('Store:').str[0].str.split('Trans:').str[1]
print (df)
                                                code                  TTT
0  Slip - Trans:S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683Store:S-BRT4Te...  S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683
1  Slip - Trans:M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459Store:M-BXP2Ter...   M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459
2  Slip - Trans:M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949Store:M-YyL2Te...  M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949
```

Your solution cann be used like:

```
df['TTT']= df['code'].str.split('Store:').str[0].str[13:]
print (df)
                                                code                  TTT
0  Slip - Trans:S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683Store:S-BRT4Te...  S-BRT4-S-BRT4-98683
1  Slip - Trans:M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459Store:M-BXP2Ter...   M-BXP2-M-BX2-65459
2  Slip - Trans:M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949Store:M-YyL2Te...  M-YyL2-M-YyL2-93949
```

Comment: df['TTT']= df['code'].str.split('Store:').str[0].str[13:] # remove negative sign can get the right answer too

Comment: thankyou very much you have also resolved my another pending problem with "extract". Yesterday also you helped ..thanks again and best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead split on `Store:`:

```
df['TTT']= df['code'].str.split("Store:",expand=True)[1]
```

Comment: Please can you tell why find() function is not working here..?